# Gnome Shell not showing Dropbox on top panel

Tags: 13.10, gnome

Today i'am installing Gnome Shell with this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

First everything was fine, but I think there is less. A few minutes later I realized that no one Dropbox icons on gnome panel:

[image: No dropbox icons]

How do i get Dropbox icons on gnome shell ?

**EDIT**

I already installed `libappindicator1` and i can confirm Dropbox is running with `ps -e | grep dropbox` commands in terminal:

```
FirstStrike@13.10:~$ ps -e | grep dropbox
2738 ?        00:00:04 dropbox
FirstStrike@13.10:~$
```

And I aware that there Dropbox in message tray:

[image: Message Tray]

**EDIT 2**

Finally i fix it with [TopIcons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/):

[image: Dropbox icons at top panel]

But when i clicked on the icon, is just opened Dropbox folder not appear drop down menu like in Unity.

Comment: ...on my system the icon disappears after a suspend/resume cycle and you have to restart the shell to have it back...

Comment: @Rmano doesn't fix it

Comment: for me this works (ubuntu gnome 15.04), dropbox menu with right click on icon

Answer (score 2):

After installing libappindicator1 from the repositories, I had to install [TopIcons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/) and REMOVE [AppIndicatorSupport](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/) to get support working.

Comment: still same problem, no dropdown menu

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

install the dropbox app indicator by

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

You may need to logout or reboot.

Comment: is already installed